# How do I pass variables or parameters to a package from .NET?

Tags: ssis, parameters

In C#, I am calling a SSIS package.  I have to pass it 3 parameters, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

package.Variables["YOUR_VAR_1"].Value = "This is test";

package.Variables["YOUR_VAR_2"].Value = 100;

Should do the trick.